# AMI creation overwriting sshd conf changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create an AMI that does not require the pem key to be specified in order to connect.

I have created an ec2 instance based on the Amazon linux AMI. I have made the required changes to add a user

and i have changed the sshd_config and set

PasswordAuthentication no

This works and I can connect as required. But when I create an AMI of my image and build from it the sshd config is reverted.

I have tried the details in this post

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=467331

which talks about the

/etc/rc.d/rc.local
or
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg

containing settings that affect it but both mine are empty. that post is from 2015 so there is every change things have moved on. But i can't find any up to date documentation about it.

Update:

cloud config contains

```
# WARNING: Modifications to this file may be overridden by files in
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d

# If this is set, 'root' will not be able to ssh in and they
# will get a message to login instead as the default user (ec2-user)
disable_root: true

# This will cause the set+update hostname module to not operate (if true)
preserve_hostname: true

datasource_list: [ Ec2, None ]

repo_upgrade: security
repo_upgrade_exclude:
 - kernel
 - nvidia*
 - cudatoolkit

mounts:
 - [ ephemeral0, /media/ephemeral0 ]
 - [ swap, none, swap, sw, "0", "0" ]
# vim:syntax=yaml
```

but i did find a folder in this dir call cloud.config.d

and it had the following files in it

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  141 Oct 10  2014 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1963 Nov 16 20:17 05_logging.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  586 Nov 18 01:38 10_aws_yumvars.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2609 Jan 31 11:43 00_defaults.cfg
```

the 00_defaults file has this line in it

ssh_pwauth: false

searching google shows that this is the setting I need to change to true. I have done that but running

sudo /usr/bin/cloud-init -d init

shows it is running that file, but it does not make any changes to sshd_config.

does it only execute completly if I build an image from it?

Comment: The AMI contains what you want. The problem actually occurs on first boot. [Check this](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/dir_layout.html).

Comment: I checked all of that over but all of the files are empty.  I can't see what is running that overwrites the sshd.

Comment: `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` is empty?

Comment: added an update